# Retrieving values from Nested Json Array into google sheets

Tags: multidimensional-array

I am having trouble getting the values of a nested object.

I have managed to retrieve the Json file from an API connection and parsed the response successfully

I am using Google Sheets and have created an App script to retrieve the data and post it into the Google Sheet.  I can successfully retrieve the FIRST object in the array which posts into different rows (perfect!)  However, the second object within the array returns the values as below:

```
 {promo_credits=null, parking_trucks=null, postevent_technical_notes=null}
 {promo_credits=null, parking_trucks=null, postevent_technical_notes=null}
 {promo_credits=null, parking_trucks=null, postevent_technical_notes=null}
 {promo_credits=null, parking_trucks=null, postevent_technical_notes=null}'
```

I wish for this data to appear separated into different columns.

I understand that I need a second loop in order to extrapolate the data?

I have tried:

for (var i = 0; i = blah.length; i ++) {

var value = [];

```
for (var j = 0; j = 10; j++){

 value.push(j);

}

 values.push(value);

 Logger.log(values[0][1]);
}
```

and also     (which i know does not have a second loop)

```
  var blah = data['data'];
 blah.forEach(function(element) {
 Logger.log(blah);
 values.push([element.items]);
  })
```

Using this second method, I can successfully  post the data into the sheet by using

```
 sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, values.length, 
values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

Using http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/  I can see the data.

[Collapsed Tree Example - As you can in there are 4 objects within this data, there could be more or less after each call to the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kzjc.png)

[Expanded Example - An expanded view example showing the ITEMS object which is what i wish to loop through. Again, there could be more or less fields within the obje](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWGiO.png)

[Example output in Google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIxBi.png)

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output you want? Of course, please remove your personal information. By the way, do you want to achieve your issue using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your response.  I have edited the question to include the parsed data and example output of where I got to!  And yes my intention is to use Google Apps Script

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your issue. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.